# LINQ to Entities causing exception in .NET Core, "Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working on trying to convert our companies framework from EF6 to be compatible with EF Core. I've run into a bit of a block. An EF "stored procedure" that works just fine on EF6 is now failing on this block of code in EF Core:

```
var allFolderAncestors = (from f in context.MENU_MenuFolders
                          from mtf in context.MENU_MenuToolbar_MenuFolders
                                             .Where(x => x.MenuFolderId == f.Id 
                                                      || x.MenuFolderId == f.ParentFolderId)
                                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where (toolbarId == -1 
                          || (mtf == null 
                                ? false 
                                : mtf.MenuToolbarId == toolbarId)
                          ) 
                          && f.Id != 0
                          select new
                          {
                              AncestorFolderId = f.Id,
                              AncestorParentFolderId = f.ParentFolderId,
                              Id = f.Id,
                              ParentFolderId = f.ParentFolderId
                          }).ToList();
```

Trying to execute this line of code results in the following exception message:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: left
```

In our .NET Core solution, this code **DOES** work when the input parameter `toolbarId` is set to -1. So my guess is the problem lies somewhere in the other side of the OR clause. And that's where I'm stuck. I was wondering if anyone has seen this problem before and knows how to fix it? Or how EF Core differs from EF6? I've tried several different fixes and looked in several places for a solution and have come up empty.

Comment: Are either MENU_MenuFolders or MENU_MenuToolbar_MenuFolders null when toolbarId != -1?

Comment: No, toolbarId == -1 is our default case, any positive value for toolbarId should "whittle down" the records returned so to speak. I've tried running the same query in LINQPad 4 and am having no issues there either....

Comment: What was the EF version used in the working scenario (what you call .NET 4.5) - EF6 or EF Core? In other words, are you actually changing the EF?

Comment: In the working version we have EF6 installed, on our Core solution we are using the EF Core 1.1 package. I found a fix to the issue though

Comment: Then update the question and tags appropriately (if you want your post to be useful for other people). So the issue has nothing to do with .NET 4.5 or .NET Core, but EF Core (if you don't know, EF Core also supports Full .NET framework). Use `entity-framework-core` tag and replace .NET 4.5 with EF6 and .NET Core with EF Core inside the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, did a little bit more tinkering with it and found out what the issue was.

```
   var allFolderAncestors = (from f in context.MENU_MenuFolders
                             from mtf in context.MENU_MenuToolbar_MenuFolders
                                                .Where(x => x.MenuFolderId == f.Id 
                                                     || x.MenuFolderId == f.ParentFolderId)
                                                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where (toolbarId == -1 
                             || (mtf != null && mtf.MenuToolbarId == toolbarId)) 
                             && f.Id != 0
                             select new
                             {
                                 AncestorFolderId = f.Id,
                                 AncestorParentFolderId = f.ParentFolderId,
                                 Id = f.Id,
                                 ParentFolderId = f.ParentFolderId
                             }).ToList();
```

In the `where` clause after the OR, apparently .NET Core does not like the ternary operator. Hope this helps anyone else that may run into this issue.

Comment: *EF Core does not like the ternary operator* - LOL. It's simply one (of the many) current EF Core bugs.